# How to have combineReducers and custom reducers in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Currently, all of my reducers only need the data from their value of the state, so my 'rootReducer' looks like this

```
export const appReducer = combineReducers({ foo: fooReducerFunction, bar: barReducerFunction})
```

which is fine, but now I have a reducer that needs other parts of the state, and I know it can be done like this

```
export function App(state: AppState, action: AppActions): AppState {
    return {
       foo: fooReducerFunction(state.foo, action),
       bar: fooReducerFunction(state.bar, action),
       baz: bazReducerFunction({foo: state.foo, bar: state.bar}, action)
    } 
}
```

but I don't want to have to write out all of the other reducers explicity like with `foo` and `bar` when only one piece of my store needs other parts of the store. Is there any way to combine custom reducers and `combineReducers` into something like this?

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({ foo: fooReducerFunction, bar: barReducerFunction})

export function App(state: AppState, action: AppActions): AppState {
    return {
       ...appReducer,
       baz: bazReducerFunction({foo: state.foo, bar: state.bar}, action)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to combine reducers in such a way, but a simpler solution to your problem is to grab a snapshot of the redux store in your action and pass the slice of state you need to your reducer upon dispatch. If you're using `redux-thunk` for example, the following pattern should work:

```
export const actionFoo = (data) =>  {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // access slice of state first
    const { otherStateSlice } = getState()
    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_DATA, otherStateSlice, data })
  }
}
```

Comment: What would be the way to do this with combine reducers? That's a good idea, but unfortunately I don't think it's very applicable to my situation